# IIS - List of common file extensions (request filtering)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have read the CIS (Center for Internet Security) Workbench recommendations for IIS 10. They recommend to disable the ***allow unlisted file name extensions*** of ***request filtering***, and only allow used extensions. If I'm looking into the IIS-Manager then I can see there a list of disallowed extension (default settings).

Has anyone a list of common file extensions for ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: Why do you need such a list from others? You should compile a list based on the web apps on that server instead.

Comment: You are right - I have used now a powershell script to list all extensions

Comment: As far as I know, MVC5 files have the following types: .cs, .cshtml, .js, .css, .config, .asax, .ico.